# Firebase Push Notifications Technology

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Documentation explains how is the body's message but it doesn't explains which techonologies are used to send the push notifications (apart from HTTP).

Does it use HTTP o HTTPS to send them?

Does it use Multicast technology?

I would like to know how they work in a lower level.

Thanks!